# I have researched into techelet and am entirely convinced its kosher, can i just start to wear it, or do i NEED to get an official psak

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, techeles

I have done a lot of research and i hold by ptil techelet is completely kasher, can I just buy it and start wearing it, or do i need an official psak?

Comment: As with any halachic issue, you need to decide on what level you consider yourself competent to make halachic decision, and on what level you want to consult with others who are more knowledgeable. Most of us want to work ourselves up slowly.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38905/6592

Comment: @MichoelR You need a halachic authority to tell you your level of competence. If a posek says you are authorized to pasken, you can; you can't decide that on your own.

Comment: @N.T. In real life, I don't think that's true. No one ever authorized the Chofetz Chaim, as far as we know, till eventually he needed semicha for something and R' Chaim Ozer gave it to him. At least that's the story.

Comment: @N.T. I once asked Rav Moshe Heinemann shlit"a what semicha was for, and he told me, Well, if you know the answer you don't need it. It authorizes you to decide for others and be indemnified.

Comment: @MichoelR You don't need a formal semicha, but you do need "shimush talmidei chachamim." If something is black and white halacha, fine, but for something complicated like techeiles, a regular person is not authorized to decide who is right between major poskim. Unless, they were told that they have the knowledge to do so.

Comment: @MichoelR As far as the Chafetz Chaim, he definitely got haskamos to his sefarim before publishing them. He did not function as a posek before then as he chose not to let people know who he was.

Comment: @N.T. Well, haskamos are a good thing and that is the minhag, but I don't know if they are required. I think they're like the teudah on a kosher restaurant: a help to the consumer.

Comment: @N.T. Did the Chazon Ish even have that? He didn't even really go to a yeshiva.

Comment: @MichoelR The Chazon Ish definitely had to be forced into a leadership role by the Chofetz Chaim and Rav Chaim Ozer z"l before he became a public figure.

Comment: Yup. But he had been publishing important halachic treatises ("Ish") for years before that happened.