# Why do Rishonim ignore the ta'amei di'krah when giving pshat in a posuk?

Tags: commentaries, tehilim-psalms, trop-cantillation, parshanut-theory

Why is it that sometimes one finds that Rishonim who attempt to explain the simple pshat of a posuk in Tehillim (Eben Ezrah, Radak, Me'iri, Seforno), will ignore the ta'amei di'krah  (the simanim that tell you where to make stops in the posuk when laining) and give a pshat that doesn't fit in with the these ta'amim? (There are many examples but to just throw out the one I noticed today - Tehillim 15-4 Eben Ezrah)

Comment: what does it mean according to trup vs. ibn ezra? the trup on Tehillim (and two other books) is different from the standard, so it is hard to understand your example.

Comment: Are you wondering about Tehillim specifically?

Comment: How is this different from any other place where two people give different explanations and we accord value to both? Ex. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17249/759

Comment: @joshwaxman I think he's thinking of the first three words. If we translate back to regular trop, it's like a Legarmeih-Munach-Revii, but Ibn Ezra reads it more like Kadma-Azla-Revii as he says נבזה קשור בעיניו גם נמאס as if the pause is on בעיניו.

Comment: @DoubleAA. Yes, that's what I was referring to. And there are so many others. I'm not looking for a case specific answer though. I just wanted to understand why the Rishonim wouldn't feel limited to an explanation(s) that fits in with the ta'amim.

Comment: @MarkA. Can you address my other two comments?

Comment: This is one possible answer. Shadal shows how various Rishonim argued on trup, and argues that it is because of when they think it was written, such that it is not dispositive. Start reading here: https://sites.google.com/site/vikuach/third-night

Comment: @DoubleAA. I'm not sure what's to address. I'm not saying that it's different than anything else. I'm just asking about the justification for ignoring the "trup" in determining PSHAT. It would appear, that the any PSHAT would have to minimally coincide with the "trup".

Comment: @joshwaxman. Thank you. Definitely a good start for me. I appreciate it.

Comment: Same way they don't take the words of chazzal into account when giving their pshuto shel mikra pshatim.

Comment: @user6591. I have no problem with Rishonim ignoring  the words of chazal in order to give peshuto shel mikrah.  I have a problem with them ignoring the posuk itself.

Comment: Tamei dikra is not the passuk itself. Just like nekudos are not the passuk itself. Just like drashos are not the passuk itself.

Comment: @user6591. By that, do you mean that the nekudos and ta'amei di'krah were not given at Har Sinai? Or do you mean that they were, but that they were only intended as a second or third layer of interpretation and not as part of the peshuto shel mikrah?