# Sources on the parameters of Eilu VeEilu

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, machlokes

There's a concept [in the gemarra](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.13b.10) known as Eilu VeEilu:

> יצאה בת קול ואמרה אלו ואלו דברי אלהים חיים הן
>
> Ultimately, a Divine Voice emerged and proclaimed: Both these and those are the words of the living God.

I'm wondering if there are any sources that discuss the parameters of such a concept. When does it apply? To who? Is this related to [shivim panim latorah](https://www.sefaria.org/Bemidbar_Rabbah.13.16)? I'm assuming some Achronim discuss how far this idea goes. For example, Pachad Yitzchok Chanukah 3:4 writes

> הוא היסוד כי גם השיטה הנידחית מהלכה דעת תורה היא, **אם רק נאמרה לפי גדרי המשא ומתן של תורה שבעל פה**‏

This sounds kind of broad and I'm not sure where it applies.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61980/malbim-on-eilu-v-eilu I'm not sure if that's a duplicate as I'm looking for any and all sources

Comment: According to some (IIRC R. Yehuda of Paris) this relates to multiple contradictory statements having been given to Moshe at Sinai. (Related to 70 panim l'torah). The other option is the opposite; that it relates to lo bashamayim hi. Whatever Man concludes is binding.

Comment: Are you asking for a list of sources who discuss it, or you want to know what they say?

Comment: @Y-ez both would obviously be more helpful