# What can not be a legitimate Orthodox interpretation of the Torah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parshanut-theory

I understand that in theory everyone can interpret the Torah and find his own Chiddushim from a renown Rabbi to a secular Jew, young and old, Jew and non-Jew. Today we can see myriads of Perushim and whole books by secular Jews and non-Jews with no relation or foundation to our tradition.

**Are there any rules that cannot be broken by interpreters** that we, the Orthodox Jews will see as legitimate? Or, on the other hand, what interpretation we can clearly say are illegitimate in our view?

For example, can one tell a Chidush that contradicts Rashi, or Gemmorah or the 13 principles?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27246/3

Comment: Is the purpose of a chiddush to teach a lesson based on the Torah, or is its purpose to tell over a historically accurate description of the Torah?

Comment: @Ezra I was thinking of interpretations, questioning historical authenticity of the Torah is different

Comment: See https://jewishaction.com/?p=17321

Comment: @msh210 Thank you, Here's the bottom-line: *"Some of the traditional commentators display remarkable creativity explaining Scripture in a way that deviates substantially from Chazal. I cannot tell you whether a particular interpretation has crossed the line. Such a decision often requires the intuition of a gadol. However, ultimately, we must always treat the words of Chazal with reverence and accept that sometimes there are even limits on peshat.*"

Comment: @msh210 Can you please summarize the article and post it as an answer because I'm afraid the link will not last long.

Comment: By all means go ahead.

Comment: How do you know if your interpretation of what can be a legitimate interpretation is itself a legitimate interpretation?