# Was Rabbi Moshe Feinstein ever formally ordained? (Given semicha?)

Tags: history, rabbis, moshe-feinstein, semicha

Did Rabbi Moshe Feinstein ever formally receive semicha? From whom? I recall reading that he studied a great deal with his father, and that his first responsum was written "at his father's orders."

Comment: He gave _s'micha_. Does that not mean he had it? (I know [we don't have the real _s'micha_ nowadays](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7494), but I seem to think the same only-one-who-has-it-can-give-it rule is in use for what we call _s'micha_. I could be totally wrong, though.)

Comment: @msh210, that's what makes it all the more curious. Though if his father ordered him to write responsa that's clearly a license to render halachic decisions; just wondering if they ever put something in paper as we're used to.

Comment: Are you asking whether someone gave him Semichah as (LeHavdil) a degree/certificate? Or are you asking whether someone gave him authority in the eyes of Halachah to render Pesak?

Comment: How is this "Judaism not Jews"???

Answer (score 8):

He (Rav Moshe) studied with his father and also in yeshivas located in Slutsk, Shklov and Amstislav, before being appointed rabbi of Lubań where he served for sixteen years. 
[(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Feinstein)

He (Rav Moshe)joined the yeshiva of R' Isser Zalman Meltzer in Slutzk at the age of twelve, where he also learned under the tutelage of HaRav Pesach Pruskin, zt"l. When the latter opened his own yeshiva in Shklov, R' Moshe went with him and recounted that at the grand opening ceremony of the new yeshiva, R' Isser Zalman himself was present. 
[Dei'ah veDibur](http://www.chareidi.org/archives5761/tezave/features.htm)

There seems to be no lack of Rabbis that would have/could have given Reb Moshe smicha aside from his father, however I was unable to find an establishment that would have given him smicha, however I am not even sure how many establishments of that nature existed during his early years.

Comment: When Pruskin sought to break away from Slutzk and start his own yeshiva, the dispute was adjudicated by R' Dovid Feinstein of Uzda (R' Moshe's father), who authorized a certain number of Slutzk students to join the new yeshiva.

Comment: R' Moshe's older brother had died in his college-age years while studying away from home; hence Moshe was sent to various yeshivas as a younger teen, but spent his next years learning with his father. Regardless of brilliance, it's incredibly rare to ordain someone less than 18 or so, just as a matter of maturity. He could have gone around to someone for an individual semicha in his late teens or early 20s (he received a personal blessing from the Chofetz Chaim for instance), but I'm not aware that he did. Then again he was hastily given a pulpit to dodge the Russian draft.

Comment: @Shalom: R. David HaLivni Weiss got semicha at 15, as he recounts in his wonderful memoir "The Book and the Sword", so it really depends on the illui and the area of Europe he lived in.

Comment: I heard that the Chafetz Chayim didn't receive Semikhah until he was more than halfway finished with his Mishnah Berurah.  Can anyone verify?

Comment: @AdamMosheh I heard he only received it (through a telegram from R' Chaim Brisker) when he needed it for a passport late in his life.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I believe it was R' Chaim Ozer Grozinski, who was a posek; not R' Chaim Brisker, who was a theoretician (and deferred to the town *dayan* R' Simcha Reiger for practical psak.)

Comment: @Shalom - Logically, what you are saying is more mistaber.  I'm not sure where I heard what I wrote on January 10th.  We should all try to find sources and stop relying on hearsay and memory.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin no, as shalom said in reply to you, it was through a telegram from Rabbi Ozer Grodzinsky see the answer that includes a source too and corrected joe shmoe's answer  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/posek-vs-rabbi/3403#3403

Comment: @Shalom R' Chaim Brisker did sometimes give semicha: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/128909/rabbinical-testing-in-volozhin/128911#comment438674_128911

Comment: This doesn't really answer the Q. The Q isn't who he COULD have gotten smicha from, the Q is who, if anyone, he DID get smicha from.