# How does one 'learn' how to paskin?

Tags: rabbis, halacha-theory, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

When a person goes through smicha (in order to become a Rabbi) they learn (at least) the laws of kashrus. Depending on the program this can include more or less amounts of information (more or less amounts of commentaries). My question is: paskening requires more than actually holding the correct range of information in your head, it involves application of that information, very often to a situation where there are conflicting valid opinions. How does one go about learning how to do THAT?
And... has anyone seen any literature on this topic?

Comment: See how others do it.

Comment: Very similar to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1098 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6979.

Comment: Shimush is needed to paskin

Comment: Example how to Pasken-if the Shulhan Aruch writes that an item that is Mukse Mishum Keli Shemalchtu Leisur is Mutar to move Lesorech Gufo Umkomo a way to Pasken would be to say that it is Mutar to use hammer to break open a nut.