# Different types of roles

Tags: rabbis

There are a lot of different titles in Judaism

Are they rabbis and what do you need to have the title of

1. Posek
2. Mekubal
3. Gaon
4. Shochet
5. Sofer
6. Hazzan

Comment: Perhaps you should split these into separate questions?

Answer (score 2):

The above mentioned titles are quite different and most of them are not rabbis.

- A *posek* is a halachic decisor. See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1098/11501).
- A *mekubal* is a kabbalist, someone who knows Kabbalah in depth. Many people who call themselves mekubalim are [fake](http://www.wherewhatwhen.com/article/mekubal-or-con-artist-don-t-get-fooled).
- A *gaon* is a genius. Very few rabbis deserve the title, and it gradually emerges as a title of respect from the community.
- A [*schochet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shechita#Shochtim) is a ritual slaughterer. Most often he is not a rabbi. In some countries there are exams to become one.
- A [*sofer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofer) is a scribe. Sometimes, but not often, he is a rabbi as well. In Israel, soferim can be certified through specific [exams](http://mezuzahdr.com/vaad-mishmeret-stam/).
- A [*hazzan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazzan) is a cantor. Often they are not rabbis. One can train for this, but there are no exams.